# Will Migration Assistant really take 52 hours to transfers my files?

Tags: migration-assistant

I just bought a new 2012 MacBook Pro and Migration Assistant says it will take 52 hours and 30 minutes to transfer. Is it really going to take that long? The blue bar is almost done.

Comment: How much data is being transferred and how is the drive/machine containing the old data connected to the new one? It's entirely possible.

Comment: Mine's the same. 50+ hours for 100GB of data from an external USB3 Time Machine backup, transferring from my air to my new top-of-the-line MBP. It'd be faster to do it by memory stick and redownload everything. In fact ... I'll do that instead.